# Get File Name from HDFS FS, where file contains a specific string

Tags: unix, hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to get the file name from hadoop file system, based on the content of the file. I have more than 1000 files in a folder and each file is of 5 to 10 MB size. My requirement is to find the file name from the list, which contains a string, for example - "abc":123. (The string I need to search for is not in the file name but in the file content)

The command I currently use is

```
hdfs dfs -find <folder_path> | while read f ; do hdfs dfs -cat $f | grep '"abc":123' >/dev/null && echo $f && exit 1 ; done
```

This command works fine however, it takes around 30 minutes if the concerned file is one of the last files in the folder.

I am looking for a better command to improve the performance. Please suggest!

Answer (score 0):

> each file is of 5 to 10 MB size

This is **not** an ideal usage of HDFS...

In any case, you're downloading the content of every file here, and blocking between each.

Instead, you should write a distributed application that greps the files using MapReduce, Spark, Pig, or other Hadoop tooling you are familiar with and logs the matching file names

Note: There is a [built-in Grep tool](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/Grep), but `grep` itself gives you the matched lines, not the file names.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I dont have prior experience in hdfs hence not familiar about hadoop tooling. Will explore more into the areas you suggested, however it would be great if any sample code you can suggest.

Comment: The grep class (and other Mapreduce examples) is open source https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/examples/Grep.java